# Create a eglpbuffersurface and bind it to eglwindowsurface

Tags: c, opengl

```
/*
This Code draws a rectangle on eglwindowsurface , however intention is to draw on         pbuffersurface  which would be binded to eglwindowsurface 
*/

static void _subset_Rectf(GLfloat x1, GLfloat y1, GLfloat x2, GLfloat y2,
    GLfloat r, GLfloat g, GLfloat b)
{
    GLfloat v[4][2], c[4][4];
    int i;

    v[0][0] = x1;   v[0][1] = y1;
    v[1][0] = x2;   v[1][1] = y1;
    v[2][0] = x2;   v[2][1] = y2;
    v[3][0] = x1;   v[3][1] = y2;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c[i][0] = r;
        c[i][1] = g;
        c[i][2] = b;
        c[i][3] = 1.0;
    }

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, v);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, v);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

/*
redraw call swaps the buffers and calls draw rectangle
*/
static void redraw(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface surf, int rot)
{
    GLfloat r, g, b;

    glClearColor(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX,
        rand()/(float)RAND_MAX,
        rand()/(float)RAND_MAX,
        1);

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    r = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    g = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    b = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(rot, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(.5, .5, .5);
    _subset_Rectf( -1, -1, 1, 1, r, g, b );
    glPopMatrix();
    eglSwapBuffers( dpy, surf );
    glFinish();
}

/*main functtion*/ 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int maj, min;
    EGLContext ctx;
    EGLSurface pbuffer, screen_surf;
    EGLConfig configs[10];
    EGLint numConfigs, i;
    EGLBoolean b;
    const EGLint pbufAttribs[] = {
        EGL_WIDTH, 500,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 500,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    const EGLint screenAttribs[] = {
        EGL_WIDTH, 1024,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 768,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    Window window;
    Display *display;

    if(!(display=XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "rsadhu::ERROR: Could not open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Colormap colormap;
    XVisualInfo *pVisual;

    EGLint count;

    EGLDisplay d = eglGetDisplay(display);

    assert(d);

    if (!eglInitialize(d, &maj, &min)) {
        printf("rsadhu:: demo: eglInitialize failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    eglGetConfigs(d, configs, 10, &numConfigs);
    for (i = 0; i < numConfigs; i++) {
        EGLint id, red, depth;
        eglGetConfigAttrib(d, configs[i], EGL_CONFIG_ID, &id);
        eglGetConfigAttrib(d, configs[i], EGL_RED_SIZE, &red);
        eglGetConfigAttrib(d, configs[i], EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, &depth);
        printf("rsadhu:: %2d:  Red Size = %d  Depth Size = %d\n", id, red, depth);
    }

    ctx = eglCreateContext(d, configs[0], EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    if (ctx == EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
        return 0;
    }

    window = CreateWindow("OpenGL ES 2.0 DRI", SIZEX, SIZEY, display, d,configs[0], &colormap, &pVisual); // creates an X Window 

    pbuffer = eglCreatePbufferSurface(d, configs[0], pbufAttribs);

    if (pbuffer == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        printf("rsadhu:: failed to create pbuffer\n");
        return 0;
    }
    b = eglMakeCurrent(d, pbuffer, pbuffer, ctx);
    if (!b) {
        printf("rsadhu::make current failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    b = eglMakeCurrent(d, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT);

    screen_surf = eglCreateWindowSurface(d,configs[0],(NativeWindowType)window,NULL);;
    if (screen_surf == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        printf("rsadhu::failed to create screen surface\n");
        return 0;
    }

    b = eglMakeCurrent(d, screen_surf, screen_surf, ctx);
    if (!b) {
        printf("rsadhu::make current failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    glClearColor(0, 1.0, 0, 1);

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );

    while(1)
    {
        static int frames = 0;
        static double timeLast = GetCurrentTimeInSeconds();
        double timeCurrent = GetCurrentTimeInSeconds();

        redraw(d, screen_surf,  i*10 ); // MAIN CAL ....

        frames++;
        if (timeCurrent - timeLast >= 1.0) {
            GLfloat seconds = timeCurrent - timeLast;
            GLfloat fps = frames / seconds;
            printf("rsadhu :: %d frames in %3.1f seconds = %6.3f FPS\n", frames, seconds,fps);
            timeLast = timeCurrent;
            frames = 0;
        }

    }

    eglDestroySurface(d, pbuffer);
    eglDestroyContext(d, ctx);
    eglTerminate(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Buddy, we don't think like you do, you need to write the actual problem you're having, so that we know it likewise.

Comment: Ok Friends: I'll try to explain , actually i want to draw a rectangle on eglpbuffersurface and  then to show it , i want to copy the content from eglpbuffersurface to eglwindowsurface . I am not sure if it can be done or not , as  i am completely new to opengl and am trying multiple combinations of surfaces viz: how to draw on eglwindowsurface, eglpbuffersurface, eglpixmapsurface and combinations.My approach might be irrational , however i am trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you would want to use pbuffers still ? If your objective is to render to offscreen buffer, and bind it as texture for rendering to display, Frame Buffer Object (FBO) can be used instead and is more efficient. You can refer to [discussion in opengl forum here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168610-pBuffer-vs-PBO-vs-FBO). You can refer to code for setting up FBO in a simple manner from here [sgxperf code gist](https://gist.github.com/prabindh/8173489)

By the way, your code will render to display buffer only because you have made screen_surf the latest current surface in the *eglMakeCurrent* call.